# How to mount a HDD on PC via SSH?

Tags: hard-drive, ssh, mount, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working from home for a while and would like to mount the other HDD on my work PC (Ubuntu 14.04).

But I haven't found the correct command. I have tried:

```
   Disk /dev/sda: 512.1 GB, 512110190592 bytes
 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62260 cylinders, total 1000215216 sectors
 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disk identifier: 0x0001019b

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sda1   *       16384   671988946   335986281+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
 /dev/sda2       671989758  1000214527   164112385    5  Extended
 /dev/sda5       933263360  1000214527    33475584   82  Linux swap /     Solaris
 /dev/sda6       671989760   933263359   130636800   83  Linux

 Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 8001.6 GB, 8001563222016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 972801 cylinders, total 15628053168 sectors
 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
 Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I have tried the mount command:

```
   sudo mount -t fat /dev/sda /media/anilil/Data/
```

with several data type which throws error abt the file system.

I know that it was previously available on `/media/anilil/Data/`

Comment: try `sudo mount -t fat /dev/sda1 /media/anilil/Data/`. you cannot mount the disk itself, you have to mount a volume within it. That said, I think you mean /dev/sdb, not /dev/sda. /dev/sdb does not have a partition table and filesystem on it, so you will have to partition and format the disk. If there is data on that disk, and you believe that linux is in error, then its time to look at sdb in fdisk or gparted. Otherwise use parted to partition and format.

Comment: @FrankThomas My answer does not say to use "-t fat", even though the question says this was tried.  My reason for not using "-t fat" is that the fdisk output didn't show any FAT drives.

Answer (score 0):

You typically don't mount drives.  You mount partitions.  (In theory, you can have a filesystem volume on a drive, instead of a partition.  That is technically possible in some cases, but may be far less compatible, and is therefore rarely done, even on removable media like SD cards where multiple partitions is uncommon.)

The fdisk output, which you show, shows that /dev/sda is your drive.
What you probably want to mount is /dev/sda1

`sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /media/whatever`

or, since you specified Ubuntu, the following may be more likely:

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/whatever`

On some systems, for some filesystem types, the -t may be unnecessary.  e.g.:

`sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/another-spot`

Note: This is assuming that /dev/sda is your second drive (which is actually not commonly the case).  More commonly, /dev/sda would be your first drive, with your operating system, and a second hard drive could be using the name /dev/sdb.  (Just running `mount`, by itself, with no parameters, may help to verify what disk you booted from.)  However, your fdisk output indicates that /dev/sdb has no partitions that you can mount; it appears to be a blank disk.  That's why I didn't provide details for mounting from that disk.